# How to get sum of entire field?

Tags: jasper-reports, expression, aggregate-functions

I'm going to get the sum of a entire field in Jasper Report. I'm passing `JRTableModelDataSource` from a Java code.

**Table**

```
  Unit Price  |    Quantity
  100.00      |       5    
  150.00      |       2
  200.00      |       4
```

I'm printing these values in my report using field.

**Field Expression**

```
  $F{Unit Price}*$F{Quantity}(This is the variable named '$V{MUL}')
```

and it prints

```
500.00
300.00
800.00
```

And now I need to prints the sum of all these values such as,

```
500.00
300.00
800.00
------
1600.00
```

I need to print this `1600.00(Sum of entire Field)` in my report. 
I tried with this,

```
  SUM($V{MUL})   
  $V{MUL} is the variable that of multiplied values(500.00,300.00,800.00)
```

But I got an error. Is this possible to do or How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as shown below

```
<variable name="GrpAmount" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="keyType" calculation="Sum">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{Unit Price}*$F{Quantity}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
```